# JQuery scroll() too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have the following HTML design with 4 Divs as shown in the diagram.

```
--------------------------
 fixedHead  |  scrollHead
--------------------------
 fixedBody  |  scrollBody
--------------------------
```

My requirement is that

1. when I scroll scrollBody horizontally scrollHead should move
   horizontally.
2. when I scroll scrollBody vertically fixedBody should
       move vertically.

I am able to achieve this by doing the below code but if the tables are very big around 100 columns and 100 rows
This becomes very slow

Is there any other faster way to achieve this

```
$('.scrollBody').scroll(function() {
    $('.fixedBody').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop()); 
    $(".scrollHead").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());   
});
```

Comment: By slow, you mean it takes too long to evaluate this expression? How long does it take? Also, could you provide an example (e.g. with a JSFiddle)? It's hard to imagine for me...

Comment: @CedricReichenbach My assumption was that the actual scrolling was too slow.

Comment: You mean the animation?

Comment: So assuming you have 100 cols, and 100 rows, that's 10000 elements, assuming these are the elements with the classes you've targeted, and they all have scrollbars, it's going to take some time to update all those scrollbars.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach He means the animation duration yeah , thats what i understand.

Comment: There is no animation

Comment: Could you paste it here, so we can lay our hands on it? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @ Cedric Reichenbach The expression as such is not slow , Its just that when we incrae th numbers of rows the scrolling gets slower

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `scroll` event can take place very often — dozens of times per second — and the browser will often end up repositioning the elements more often than is strictly necessary.

A common solution to this kind of problem is 'throttling':

```
$('.scrollBody').scroll( $.throttle( 100, function() {
    $('.fixedBody').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop()); 
    $(".scrollHead").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());   
} ) );
```

The example above uses Ben Alman's [jQuery throttle / debounce plugin](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce), and basically means that the function won't execute more than once every 100 milliseconds — you can alter that figure to try and find a happy responsive medium.

Comment: I do think I see some improvement and I am playing around with the figure but still the scrolling seems to kind of slow and stuck at times

Comment: It may be better to ditch the manual throttling in favour of more recent developments then. [I've proposed a new solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953439/jquery-scroll-too-slow/21050741#21050741) that uses `requestAnimationFrame` and CSS3 `transform` to relieve pressure on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, this should make the animation last 100 ms:

```
var duration = 100;
$('.scrollBody').scroll(function() {
  $('.fixedBody').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).scrollTop() }, duration);
  $(".scrollHead").animate({ scrollLeft: $(this).scrollLeft() }, duration);
});
```

Comment: So it would be faster to animate the scrolling, than just doing it with no animation ?

Comment: No, but smoother... :P But I guess I misunderstood you, I thought you were fighting with some default animations.

Comment: I think this is actually more likely to slow it down: with jQuery animations, the DOM will only be modified more times than it is currently  — which I suspect is the performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to leverage `requestAnimationFrame` (with custom throttling) to prevent locking, and saving painting time with the repositioning by using 3D transform offsets instead of modifying `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop`.

The code I wrote didn't play well with jsFiddle or jsBin (which is a bit worrying), but worked fine locally. The table is fairly large in size, but doesn't contain a very complicated DOM (each element only contains a text node), so its performance may not be indicative.

See if this works for you ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/barneycarroll/8358510))…

The flow works as follows:

- Bind the table body's `scroll` event to a function which requests an animation frame (rather than executing immediately), unless we're already waiting on a request. Requesting an animation frame means the code will execute as and when the browser has a re-paint coming, instead of forcing it to act immediately, which means it won't block any other code.
- When the animation frame becomes available, check each axis' offset to see if it's changed since last time. If it has, apply the offset as a negative translate value on that axis. Transform is better than scroll offset for paint time since it doesn't need to recalculate any layout CSS: it just moves the existing rendering of the DOM element. 3D translate is even better since on some systems it can offset all the painting to a separate thread (the GPU), freeing up main CPU process even more.

The key elements of the code are below:

```
var $scrollBody = $( '.scrollBody' );
var $fixedBody  = $( '.fixedBody' );
var $scrollHead = $( '.scrollHead' );

void function persistScrollState(){
    var previousOffset = {
        x : 0,
        y : 0
    };
    var pendingScroll  = false;

    function persistScroll(){
        var offset = {
            x: -$scrollBody.scrollLeft(),
            y: -$scrollBody.scrollTop()
        };

        if( offset.x !== previousOffset.x ){
            $scrollHead.css( { transform : 'translateX( ' + offset.x + 'px ) translateZ( 0px )' } );
        }
        if( offset.y !== previousOffset.y ){
            $fixedBody.css(  { transform : 'translateY( ' + offset.y + 'px ) translateZ( 0px )' } );
        }

        previousOffset = offset;
        pendingScroll  = false;
    }

    $scrollBody.on( 'scroll', function handleScroll() {    
        // requestAnimationFrame to avoid resource hogging:
        // https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671
        // Use polyfill for non-supporting browsers:
        // https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671

        if( !pendingScroll ){
            pendingScroll = requestAnimationFrame( persistScroll );
        }
    } );
}();
```

Comment: Thank Barney.. Sorry i could not login and check your response . The reason was that the same code was extremly fast with IE10 and the client has indiacted that thye will be using only IE10. But i will be defintly trying out your solution and will update you .Once again thanks for taking the time and effort